# Does using std::move on pair.first invalidate pair.second?

Tags: c++, move, std-pair

I have the following code in my project at the moment :

```
std::vector<int> vectorOfFirsts;
std::set<double> setOfSeconds;
std::list<std::pair<int,double>> cachedList;
// do something to fill the list 
for (const auto& pair : cachedList)
{
   vectorOfFirsts.push_back(pair.first);
   setOfSeconds.insert(pair.second);
}
```

This list will be very big, and is only necessary for filling the vector and the set (i.e. its content can be invalidated). My question now is, if the following optimization is a good idea:

```
 for (const auto& pair : cachedList)
 {
       vectorOfFirsts.push_back(std::move(pair.first));
       setOfSeconds.insert(std::move(pair.second));
 }
```

Will calling std::move on pair.first somehow invalidate pair.second? And will this code provide any speedup for the loop? I know that it would probably be a good idea to fill the vector/set instead of the list, but the list is filled via some legacy code I have no control over / no time to dig in.

Comment: To begin with, in general you can't move from something that is `const`

Comment: FYI You should prefer `std::move(pair).first`. It's smarter because it takes reference types etc into account.

Comment: So would it help, if I remove the const qualifier of pair?

Comment: You gain nothing to `std::move` `int` or `double`. It is a copy anyway.

Comment: Also, an attempt to move primitive types falls back to a copy

Comment: Ok! So in my case attempting to move will result in copy, but in a general case (more complex objects stored in the pair), we should move?

Comment: @Stefan if you don't need `cachedList` anymore then perpahs yes, provided that you remove `const`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will calling std::move on pair.first somehow invalidate pair.second?

No. `first` and `second` are completely different variables happening to reside in some class object. Moving one does not affect the other.

> And will this code provide any speedup for the loop?

It depends on the types. The point of `move`-ing something is to transfer resources, basically. Since the pairs here are of `int`s and `double`s, there are no resources involved, so there is nothing to transfer. Had it been a pair of some matrix type and some tensor type, each with some internal dynamically-allocated buffer, then it might have improved performance.

Comment: @TonyD Many thanks for the point. I completely agree with your superior phrasing.

Answer (score 3):

Stop.

Take a moment to think about this code. Comments inline

```
// step one - iterate through cachedList, binding the dereferenced
// iterator to a CONST reference
for (const auto& pair : cachedList)
{
  // step 2 - use std::move to cast the l-value reference pair to an
  // r-value. This will have the type const <pairtype> &&. A const
  // r-value reference.
  // vector::push_back does not have an overload for const T&& (rightly)
  // so const T&& will decay to const T&. You will copy the object.
  vectorOfFirsts.push_back(std::move(pair.first));

  // ditto
  setOfSeconds.insert(std::move(pair.second));
 }
```

It needs to be:

```
for (auto& pair : cachedList)
{
  vectorOfFirsts.push_back(std::move(pair.first));
  setOfSeconds.insert(std::move(pair.second));
}
```

And yes, this then becomes a valid and legitimate use of move.